# Corrupted PDF attachment on SOST tcode

Tags: abap

I am sending email using cl_bcs class as PDF attachment.Now, when I do issue output to in VA02/03 tcode,it works and in email I can open the attachment.But,on press of save in change mode in va02 tcode,as output type is automatically triggered using condition record,it sends the mail but the PDF attachment(which is adobe form only) shows corrupted.

Any pointers?

Comment: Difficult to say anything with these few information, but generally a corrupted PDF means simply a bug in your program, in ABAP it's often because you generated extra null bytes.

Comment: `But on save event in change mode the PDF attachment in mail shows corrupted` then smth is going wrong at save event. You say manual triggering in VA02 via your class goes fine and automatic is not? maybe manual output uses standard mail generation class and automatic uses custom one or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help.I found out the solution. The reason was that the pdf from Adobe Form FM was not generating correctly.So before converting to Binary, we need to pass docparams-getpdf = X.This solved the issue and attachment is opening like charm.I am using cl_bcs class for mail functionality.